# react-router how to have two switch, without destroying the other route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

see the video first :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pZ1gN2cRnYOMEdof-JlVWjzW3QLUM4AC/view?usp=sharing

I have seen the nested route for react-router, but I am still confused.

[image]

here is my code for the parent (where I want to render all the components), if you see above, you can see there are catalog A, catalog B, etc. at the side, it will route to catalog-a, etc.

```
<BrowserRouter>
<div id="l-dashboard">
    <div style={{ flex: 8, backgroundColor: "white" }}>
    <Sw>
      <Route path="/catalog-a">
        <Catalog
          title="Category A"
        >

          <div className="hr" />
          <div className=" flex-grow-1 d-flex flex-column p-4 pt-5">
            <Product />
          </div>
          <div className=" flex-grow-5 d-flex flex-column p-4 pt-5">
            <h1>aaa</h1>
          </div>
        </Catalog>
      </Route>
      <Route path="/catalog-b">
        <Catalog
          title="Category B"
        >
          <div className="hr" />
          <div className=" flex-grow-1 d-flex flex-column p-4 pt-5">
            <Product />
          </div>
        </Catalog>
      </Route>
      <Route path="/catalog-c">
        <Catalog
          title="Category C"
        >
          <div className="hr" />
          <div className=" flex-grow-1 d-flex flex-column p-4 pt-5">
            <Product />
          </div>
        </Catalog>
      </Route>
      <Route path="/catalog-d">
        <Catalog
          title="Category D"
        >
          <div className="hr" />
          <div className=" flex-grow-1 d-flex flex-column p-4 pt-5">

            <Product />
          </div>

        </Catalog>
      </Route>
    </Sw>
  </div>
  <div style={{ flex: 8,}}>
    <ProductsDetail/>
  </div>
</div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

the ProductsDetail works here, but I can't use that because I need the route to be displayed on the right side, the route that keeps destroyed.

this is how I show the ProductsDetail using Links

```
const ConditionalLink = ({ children, to, condition }) => (!!condition && to)
    ? <Link style={{
        color:"var(--blue-1)",
    }}to={to}>{children}</Link>
    : <Link style={{
        color:"var(--blue-1)",
    }}to={to}>{children}</Link>;
{products.map(product => (
                <ConditionalLink to={`${selected?"/product-detail":"catalog-a"}`} condition={selected}>
                <li key={product.id} className={`startupcard ${product.green?"":"startupcard-green"} ${selected?"selected":" "} `}>
                    <ButtonToggle 
                    active={active === product}
                    onClick={() =>  {
                        setActive(product);
                        !selected?setSelected(true):setSelected(false);
                        setShrink(!shrink);
                    } } 

                    {...console.log(selected)}

                    className="product-button">
                        <img src={Burger} alt="" className="startupcard-image " />              
                        <div className="details">
                            <h3>{product.name}</h3>
                            <p>{product.detail}</p>
                        </div>
                        {product.green?<ClipG className="clip-svg"/>:<Clip className="clip-svg"/>}
                        
                    </ButtonToggle>
                </li>
                </ConditionalLink>
                ))}
```

my ProductsDetail is

```
function ProductsDetail() {
  return (
    <div className="products-detail-panel">
      <Sw>
      <Route path="/product-detail">
            <div className="product-details-container">
            <div className="product-head">
                <h3>
                Product Name
                </h3>
                <h3>
                SR 45.00
                </h3>
            </div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim quibusdam perspiciatis aut modi cumque quis ipsam quia ipsum magni itaque tempore vel adipisci nostrum, quod, dolores maxime. Pariatur, dolorem itaque.</p>
                <br />
                <p>Images</p>
                <hr />
            <div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </Route>
      </Sw>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Difficult to tell, are you rendering more than one router? Is `Sw` the `Switch` component? What is destroyed? Can you remove all the irrelevant non-routing-related code so it's easier to see what you are referring to?

Comment: yes ```Sw``` is ```Switch``` i do that because I use material UI too that have switch

Comment: So is your issue with the `ProductsDetail` component? You say "the ProductsDetail works here, but I can't use that because I need the route to be displayed on the right side, the route that keeps destroyed." but why can't you use `ProductsDetail` if you say it's working? What route needs to be displayed on the right side? What route that keeps what destroyed? Your question/issue is still unclear.

Comment: because if I put it there it will be displayed below the catalog A, B, C., etc., not on the side

Comment: I guess I don't follow your code or question then. Where do you want to render `ProductsDetail`? Can you update your question to include the code you are actually trying to use?